# How to end Task scheduler task gracefully

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I am running a python programm via a batch script through the windows task scheduler (Win10). It is supposed to run all the time but when I have to do maintenance I manually stop the task in the scheduler. My question is now what is happening under the hood? Is the stopping of the task equivalent to hitting ctrl+C aka a KeyboardInterrupt error in python? I want to communicate to my program that it should stop gracefully so that everything is saved and logged properly.

Currently I just abort it and feel bad about the 5 or so seconds that I lose because of it.